# Http header 304 and caching?

Tags: iis, http, cache, http-headers

*Our company uses these settings( don't ask me why) - for every request they want a new request from server. this is an intranet system which uses only IE.*

They defined it in :

[image]

We also have windows authentication `NTLM` in the `iis7`.

I have 2 questions please.

<kbd>Question #1)</kbd>

when the browser make a request ( css ) :

*(leave the 401 response for now - this is how ntlm works)*
[image]

He is requesting it with `if-modified-since` header.

why is he adding this header ? How can I configure it ? why doesn't he use the settings from IE and try to download it each time - as I showed in the first picture ?

<kbd>Question #2)</kbd>

The response ( *after ntlm negotiation*) for that was  :

Response  with `Not-modified` which is 304 header. and I assume its because we sent the request with the `if-modified-since` header.

But there is a problem.

He is actually tells me to download from my cache.

**But** I told him explicitly in the IE settings  - **not** to load from cache.

Wham am I missing here ?

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1

> why is he adding this header ?

Because the browser already has a copy of the content in the cache. This happens if

1) it's past it's expiry date

2) the browser has been configured to check for newer versions every time

> How can I configure it ?

You can't do anything about (1) - this just how HTTP works. For (2), change the config to check "Automatically"

Q2

> But I told him explicitly in the IE settings - not to load from cache.

No - the instruction to the browser was to *check* for a newer version - the webserver will only return a new version (with a 200 response) if the conditional parts of the request are matched.

Comment: I deleted the browser cache completetly (ccleaner) and still it showed me 304....he surely doesnt have the copy...so how ?

Comment: If you deleted the cache then how could the browser supply a date against which to check if it has been modified since? You have not deleted the cache.

Answer (score 0):

**The setup you are asking for is a very bad idea.** If you actually roll this out, everything will seem to load slower. Every server you connect to is going to get hammered into smithereens. I don't know why you're being asked to do this, but **you should find out why, so that you can come up with a reasonable solution to whatever the real problem is.**

**Plus, you can't do it with Internet Explorer at all.** It has no way to completely disable use of caching (Temporary Internet Files).

One situation you may be running into is with people with roaming profiles having large IE caches that end up getting copied around the network. If this is what the real problem is, then you can [tell IE to empty the cache when it exits](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185255/en-us). There will no longer be any large file copies going on, at least with respect to IE's cache.